# Java Server Page Param confusion

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

When `jsp:include` or `jsp:forward` is executed, the included page or forwarded
page will see the original request object, with the original parameters
augmented with the new parameters and new values taking precedence over
existing values when applicable.

For example, if the request has a parameter
`Lname=abc` and a parameter `Lname=xyz` is 
specified for forward, the forwarded request 
will have `Lname=xyz, abc`.

The new parameter has precedence

Please explain with an example.

Comment: m sorry but i dont have any jsp code it just  I am unable to understand this as "When jsp:include or jsp:forward is executed, the included page or forwarded page will see the original request object, with the original parameters augmented with the new parameters and new values taking precedence over existing values when applicable.

For example, if the request has a parameter Lname=abc and a parameter Lname=xyz is specified for forward, the forwarded request will have Lname=xyz, abc.

have Lname=xyz, abc" how is it done  it will be good for m if ill get some code to understand this

Answer (score 2):

Lets understand main difference between jsp:include and jsp:forward.

jsp:include, includes the page inside the current page. So the included page will appear exactly where u have added the jsp command inside the current page.

e.g.

```
...
<jsp:include page="inc/include.jsp" />
...
```

but jsp:forward will forward the current page to the forwarded page. Meaning when the current page is called the forwarded page is called immediately after.

e.g.

```
if (...) { forwarded to pageOne.jsp }
else if (...) { forwarded to pageTwo.jsp }
```

Now following is the way we can access parameters for both jsp:forward and jsp:include.

jsp:include : we can access parameters using param not by request object.
e.g.

```
${param.param1}
```

while in jsp:forward : we can access parameters using request object.
e.g.

```
request.getParameter("param1")
```

This is what the main difference between the parameters in jsp:inlcude and jsp:forward. And thus, we are getting new value in jsp:forward (say Lname=xyz).

example:

say we have a parameter Lname=xyz in request object. In current jsp it can be accessed using below code

```
<%= (String)request.getParameter("Lname"); %> <%-- This will print xyz on jsp --%>
```

Now, further the same parameter name can be used with jsp:forward, like...

```
<jsp:forward page="fwd/pageOne.jsp?Lname=abc" />
```

or

```
<jsp:forward page="fwd/pageOne.jsp">
    <param name="Lname" value="abc"/>
</jsp:forward>
```

This will result Lname=abc in fwd/pageOne.jsp using request.getParameter() method.

Thanks

Comment: Thanx but how can i display Lname=xyz, abc if the request has a parameter Lname=abc and a parameter Lname=xyz is specified for forward and  with the original parameters augmented with the new parameters and new values taking precedence over existing values when applicable. how can i display this example

Comment: As per my understanding to your comment, I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know in case of any concern.